# Is it true that (L\a + L\b,L) = 1. L=$lcm(a,b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $a$ is  different from $b$ and $L=lcm(a,b)$.Is it true that (L\a + L\b,L) = 1$ ?

How do I approach this one? Should I write the Bezout's Theorem??

Comment: You must exclude negative $a,b,\;$ otherwise it is wrong for $b=-a; |a| > 1$

Comment: By L\a is it meant L/a?

Comment: Yes it means / sorry

Answer (score 1):

It is not true: take $a=6$ and $b=10$. Then $L=30$ and $\dfrac La+\dfrac Lb=8$, which are not coprime.